# Doit-on accorder une métonymie?

Tags: accord

Je viens d'entendre, dans un restaurant, le serveur commander en cuisine "deux bœuf Stroganoff". Comme ça sonnait faux à mon oreille, j'ai mentalement corrigé "deux bœuf**s** Stroganoff".

Puis, j'ai compris qu'il s'agissait d'une métonymie et qu'il commandait en fait "deux ragouts de bœuf Stroganoff".

En fin de compte, le serveur avait-il raison ou doit-on accorder un mot lorsqu'il fait partie d'une métonymie?

Comment: Je ne comprends pas bien la question. Pour moi  « Stroganoff » n'est pas une métonymie, c'est le nom d'un plat - nom composé d'un nom et d'un qualificatif, comme un bœuf bourguignon  (un bœuf carottes, une crème anglaise, etc...). Je n'ai jamais vu écrit sur un menu (ou entendu dire) deux « ragouts de bœuf bourguignon/Stroganoff... ». Par ailleurs, à l'écrit j'écrirais bien « 2 bœufs Stroganoff » mais « bœufs » se prononçant  /bø/ (du moins en France) je ne vois pas comment on entendrait le pluriel à l'oral.

Comment: Non, "Stroganoff" n'est pas une métonymie, mais "bœuf(s)" oui, c'est sur ce mot que porte ma question. Concernant la prononciation, je dis 1 /bœf/, 2 /bø/ (rimant avec "œuf(s)").

Comment: Une petite recherche m'a permis de voir que certains parlent effectivement de « ragout de bœuf  » (bourguignon, Stroganoff...) mais je ne pense pas que ce soit le plus courant, et ça ne change rien au fait que dans  « deux bœufs Stroganoff » le s de bœufs est muet, donc la parole du serveur est correcte pour moi. Ou alors le serveur a prononcé /bœf/ ? La question ne le dit pas. Ce ne serait pas une prononciation « puriste » mais on ne peut s'attendre à ça dans le feu du travail rapide de la salle et des cuisines !

Comment: Je confirme que le serveur a prononcé /bœf/, ce qui est une prononciation correcte (ou puriste?). Merci de ne pas prendre ton régionalisme pour une généralité.

Comment: L'élément du menu (*bœuf Stroganoff*) est considéré comme un nom propre. Ce n'est pas rééllement un boeuf entier, (même chose pour "deux porc caramélisé"). A une foire aux bestiaux, on mettra toujours un pluriel pour dire "deux boeufs charolais".